# popup.html not displaying correctly

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am just beginning to learn how to make chrome extensions and I have encountered a problem. When I click on my extension, the popup.html does not display correctly. Sometimes it does not display at all, other times it appears like this:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Blocker",
  "description": "Blocks things",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "window.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

And my window.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body height="300px" width="300px">
    <div>Hello, world!</div>
    <img src="icon.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome since there's nothing wrong in the posted code. Try the usual troobleshooting steps like disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome settings, resetting chrome://flags, creating a new empty profile and testing the extension there, and so on

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: There are 2 problems with the height/width attributes on the body element (they wouldn't use 'px' but they aren't valid on a body element.) It is possible legacy logic for to support that is throwing off hardware acceleration. So I would try using a style element with your desired CSS and see if hardware acceleration works again..